# get the correct ethernet interface in use on Linux system

Tags: linux, bash

Most systems such as laptops have two interfaces... I need the main device that is being used by the system (assuming there is only one) such as  eth0 wlan0 or whatever RHEL7 is trying to do...

The best I hacked together was this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -- Get me the interface for the main ip on system

for each in $(ls -1 /sys/class/net) ;do 

    result=$(ip addr show $each | awk '$1 == "inet" {gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $2); print $2}' | grep "$(hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1)")

    if [ ! -z "${result// }" ] && [ -d /sys/class/net/${each// } ] ;then
            echo "Device: $each IP: $result"
            break;
    fi

done
```

Sample output:

```
    ./maineth.sh  
    Device: enp0s25 IP: 192.168.1.6
```

This method is assuming that hostname -I is providing the main ip first

Comment: maybe this   ip -o link show | awk '{print $2,$9}'

Comment: Mike, what you do in the comment gives me a list of all interfaces and their status, which is not what do in your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a slightly simpler version to the OPs:

```
 ip a | awk 'BEGIN{ "hostname -I|cut -d\" \" -f 1" | getline ip} $2 ~ ip {print "Device: "$NF "  IP: "$2}'
```

Comment: @MikeQ :  Excellent :) ... that's what we're here for, right? :}

Answer (score 1):

Heres another way:

```
ip addr show | grep "state UP"
```

Here is a small script that will show statistics so you can verify which is most active:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ip link | grep "state UP" | awk '{ print $2 }') ; do
  ip -s link show ${i/:}
done
exit
```

Comment: You can head -1, if you have more than one active port and want just the main one shown

Answer (score 0):

This may be sufficient, if someone else answers I will give credit:

```
  $ nmcli dev status | grep -i "wired" | awk '{print $1}' | head -1
  enp0s25

  $ nmcli dev status | grep -i "wifi" | awk '{print $1}' | head -1
  wlp3s0
```

Comment: note: network manager is not standard to all distributions (probably less than 1/2)